# Reverse Singular Polymorphism with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having issues comprehending how polymorphism would work in my particular application. I have read the [rails guides on polymorphism](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) but I feel that it is the opposite of what I want to do. Furthermore the data is too different to use Single Table Inheritance (STI).

Any one message will relate with only one of the three models (e.g. Mobile, Letter, Email). Conversely, the Mobile, Letter or Email models will only belong to one message.

My end goal is to supplement the Message view with the supplied data of the messages' respective supporting model (Mobile, Letter or Email).

Would the model logic below allow my Message to only have one supporting model.

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :messageable, polymorphic: true

  # Examples of Message Data
  # Subject
  # Message
  # Mobile, Letter or Email?
end

class Mobile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :message, as: :messageable 

  # Examples of Mobile Data
  # First and Last Name
  # Telephone Number
  # User Agent String
  # Operating System
end

class Letter < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :message, as: :messageable 

  # Examples of Letter Data
  # First and Last Name
  # Sender Address
  # Destination Address
  # Stamp Value in Cents
end

class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :message, as: :messageable 

  # Examples of Email Data
  # Sender Email
  # Recepient Email
  # Ip Address
end
```

Ideally I would like to access data within my views similar to some of the examples below.

```
# display a user agent string for a mobile message
@message.user_agent_string

# display the stamp value for a Letter
@message.letter_value

# display the ip address for a EmaiL
@message.ip_address
```

Thanks for your time in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two major problems:

#### 1. Literally the relationship method is incorrect as per Rails doc.

`polymorphic: true` should be on `belongs_to` part. And `as: :messageable` should be on `has_one` or `has_many` part.

#### 2. The main problem is the modelling is incorrect

Letter, Email, or Mobile are all kind of messages, they neither belong to nor have message, they ARE message. So, such relationship is not necessary, in fact they should have relationship with one who'll send or receive the message.

The interface would be look like this

```
sender = User.find(123)
receiver = User.find(456)
message = Letter.new(sender, receiver) # or Email, Mobile
message.send

# or
message = Message.new(sender, receiver, type: :letter)
message.send
```

I don't know other details of your app so I can't give detailed relationship suggestion here.

Comment: Billy thanks for your thorough feedback. I am beginning to understand your logic behind point number one. Most of the examples I find have a has_many relationship which is why it confused me. To further clarify what I want to do, I want to display a list all types of messages (Letter, Email, Mobile) on the messages view. Is that possible using your suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the model logic seems to be correct.

However, you may not be able to use  something like `@message.user_agent_string` directly [though I am not sure].

You can get `messageable_id` from `@message`. Then you need to know which model (`Letter`/`Email`/`Mobile`) has that `messageable_id`. If you know it already, that's good. Otherwise you may need to search all entries of three model to find that record. You can use `find_by` for that. Once you have found the entry, you can use `@value.user_agent_string` or `@value.letter_value` or `@value.ip_address` depending on situation.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I was over thinking this and Billy Chan has set me in the right direction. For future stackers, this is how I solved my issue.

Models I used to solve this problem.

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :messageable, polymorphic: true
end

class Mobile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :message, as: :messageable
end

class Letter < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :message, as: :messageable
end

class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :message, as: :messageable
end
```

Controller I used to solve this problem

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @messages = Message.all
  end

  def show
    @mobile = Mobile.find_by(messageable_id: params[:id])
    @letter = Letter.find_by(messageable_id: params[:id])
    @email = Email.find_by(messageable_id: params[:id]) 
  end
end
```

I was able to call the message show view and did partials for mobile, letter and email. My next step is to render only those views if a record with messageable_id matches the id of the message.